# Кэширование формы логина в ExtJS

Tags: extjs

C `ExtJS` работаю сравнительно недавно. Нужно параметры формы логина добавить в куки (текстовое поле логина и пара комбо-боксов), чтобы при следующем входе в систему сразу выдавал эти параметры. Про `Ext.util.Cookies` и `CookieProvider` слышал, но достаточно разобранного примера не нашел. Буду рад любой информации по теме.

Comment: Вам обязательно куки нужны?
Используйте лучше `localStorage`.

Comment: В проекте используется версия 3.3. localStorage там еще нет

Comment: Да при чем здесь 3.3 :)  
Используйте нативный JS для работы с `localStorage`.

Comment: Локальное хранилище реализовано в браузере, а не как вы считаете, в какой-то библиотеке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит чаще пользоваться официально документацией и примерами.
Три основных метода для работы с куками

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set(); // Назначить 
Ext.util.Cookies.get(); // Получить
Ext.util.Cookies.clear(); // Очистить
```

Задал значение:

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set("login", yourField.getValue() );
```

Получил значение:

```
var cookieLogin = Ext.util.Cookies.get("valid");
yourField.setValue(cookieLogin);
```

В чем, собственно, проблема?